# best way to change current site language

Tags: php

i am creating a website by two language with php. to change language of pages , i create to link like this:

```
<a href="/?lang=fa">FA</a>|<a href="/?lang=en">EN</a>
```

this two link is on a page named ***header.php*** that includes on some page.but in some pages is some parameters that send via URL . So that two link are not true and they Should be as follows:

```
<a href="aPage.php?id=1&lang=en">FA</a>|<a href="aPage.php?id=1&lang=en">EN</a>
```

my Question is how i create a dynamic links for all page Even if have some parameters.

Comment: I'd keep the language choice in the session...

Comment: store the language choice in the session, build pages using that session setting. and on each page, you put ONE link that switches to the other language. e.g. english page/farsi link. farsi page/english link.

Comment: yes i do it too. but it is possible user click on one of two links in a page that have some already sent parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
<?
$params = $_GET;
$params['lang'] = 'EN';
$qs = '?';
foreach($params as $k=>$v)
  $qs .= $k.'='.urlencode($v).'&';
$url = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].$qs, 0, -1);

echo $url; //EN

$params['lang'] = 'FR';
$qs = '?';
foreach($params as $k=>$v)
  $qs .= $k.'='.urlencode($v).'&';
$url = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].$qs, 0, -1);

echo $url; //FR
?>
```

Comment: Hugo Delsing,thanks, yes it is my answer . but by your solution always add a addition & at the end of URL. how to remove it ?

Comment: You can create another array which elements are the string "$k=$v" instead of concatenate the `$qs`, after that use `$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?' . $implode('&',$newArr)`

Comment: Updated it with the use of http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php to remove the last &. But an extra & doesnt realy matter. Also keep in mind that google doesnt like multiple languages like this and will give you a penalty. You will serve different content on the same URL based on a session var

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the value in a global key, preferable php's `$_SESSION`

in the beginnen of your page you can then check with the following :

```
session_start(); // if not started already
$possible_languages = array('en', 'fr');
$default_language   = 'fr';

$_SESSION['lang'] = ( isset($_GET['lang']) && in_array($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : $default_language );
```

From now on you can `$_SESSION['lang']` where needed

Answer (score 0):

First, store the language in session or cookie.

Second, build link creation mechanism for your website using the current language setting, do not `echo` the internal links directly. Important internal links should be created from functions so that they format can be change quickly later.